# C# - Outlook VSTO - Getting AdvancedSearchComplete to trigger

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin, add-in

I am converting an old Outlook VBA macro I created to a C# VSTO Add-in.  This tool is for bulk archiving of emails to various public folders and a local .pst file and needs to be able to find emails based on a user's search criteria. I had a whale of a time getting the `AdvancedSearchComplete` event to trigger in VBA, but eventually got it to work. Of course, I am now have the same problem in the C# VSTO add-in.

To use the tool, the user will input their criteria on a userform, then click the <kbd>Find Emails</kbd> button to perform the search with the results populating a datagridview.

```
public partial class Email_Archiver : Form
{

    public Email_Archiver()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        //Add event handlers
        Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.AdvancedSearchComplete += new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.ApplicationEvents_11_AdvancedSearchCompleteEventHandler(Application_AdvancedSearchComplete);
    }

    public void Application_AdvancedSearchComplete(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Search SearchObject)
    { //Handles AdvancedSearchComplete event

        if (SearchObject.Tag == "Archiver Search")
        {
            OutlookFunctions.SearchComplete = true;
            MessageBox.Show(this, "Search Complete!","Email Search Error",MessageBoxButtons.OK);
        }

    }

    private void Find_Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        //Set datagridview datasource
        EmailList.DataSource = FindEmails();
        EmailList.Columns["EntryID"].Visible = false;

    }

    public DataTable FindEmails()
    {
        var dt = new DataTable();

        //Format DataTable
        dt.Columns.Add("EntryID", typeof(string));
        dt.Columns.Add("Project No.", typeof(int));
        dt.Columns.Add("Subject", typeof(string));
        dt.Columns.Add("Sender", typeof(string));
        dt.Columns.Add("Recipient", typeof(string));
        dt.Columns.Add("Time Sent", typeof(DateTime));
        dt.Columns.Add("Size", typeof(decimal));

        //Do stuff to get "searchFolders" and "searchCriteria" from form
        //...

        dt = OutlookFunctions.RunAdvancedSearch(searchFolders, searchCriteria);

        return dt;
    }
}


class OutlookFunctions
{

    public static bool SearchComplete;

    public static DataTable RunAdvancedSearch(string[] searchFolders, string[] searchCriteria)
    {

        //Get Outlook namespace
        var oApp = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application;
        var oNS = oApp.GetNamespace("mapi");
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Search advSearch = null;

        //Do other stuff to properly set up the scope and filter
        //...

        //Perform search
        SearchComplete = false;
        try
        {
            advSearch = oApp.AdvancedSearch(scope, filter, false, "Archiver Search");
        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("An error has occurred during the search for emails. \n \n"
                    + ex.Message);
            return null;
        }

        Stopwatch timer = new Stopwatch();
        timer.Start();

        while (!SearchComplete && timer.Elapsed.TotalSeconds < 10)
        {
            //Do nothing
        }

        if (!SearchComplete)
        {
            advSearch.Stop();
        }

        if (advSearch != null)
        {
            var resultTable = new DataTable();

            //Send results to resultTable

            return resultTable;
        }

        return null;

    }

}
```

The search works and I get the proper results, but I had to add in the timer to make things move along, otherwise the code never finishes because `AdvancedSearchComplete` isn't triggered. I still get all of the emails I'm looking for and doing essentially the same search just in the Outlook explorer, I get the same results in a fraction of a second.

After the timer ends the search and the datagridview is filled with the results, THEN the `AdvancedSearchComplete` fires and I get my "Search Complete!" message.

What am I missing here that is keeping the event from triggering to end the search (in a timely fashion)?

Comment: I would use a taskpane in lieu of a userform. I would also use a `BackgroundWorker` in the button click. Then you can use the `DoWork`, `ProgressChanged` and `RunWorkerCompleted` events.

Comment: Yes, you can use backgroundwork (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker?view=netframework-4.7.2) which is mentioned by aduguid. Post some samples code as answer.

Comment: I like the idea of making this a taskpane, so thank you for that suggestion @aduguid! I will look into the BackgroundWorker some more as well, but my understanding is that the AdvancedSearch is essentially its own BackgroundWorker already. There just seems to be an error either with my code or how I'm running the search that is keeping it from working as expected.

Comment: After frustratingly playing around with this a bit more, it seems that if there is ANY code to be executed after the AdvancedSearch method is called, then AdvancedSearchComplete will not fire correctly. I'm still testing this out, but I think that means I am going to have to rearrange everything so that the remainder of the code is executed in the AdvancedSearchComplete method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that any code following the initiation for the AdvancedSearch method will essentially end the search without triggering the AdvancedSearchComplete or AdvancedSearchStopped events.

Instead, I now have the following in the ThisAddIn class:

```
private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    //Create task pane object
    archiverTaskPane1 = new ArchiverTaskPane();
    customTaskPane = this.CustomTaskPanes.Add(archiverTaskPane1, "Title");

    //Add event handler for opening task pane
    customTaskPane.VisibleChanged += new EventHandler(customTaskPane_VisibleChanged);

    //Add event handler for Outlook's AdvancedSearch
    Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.AdvancedSearchComplete += new Outlook.ApplicationEvents_11_AdvancedSearchCompleteEventHandler(Application_AdvancedSearchComplete);
}

public void Application_AdvancedSearchComplete(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Search SearchObject)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    OutlookFunctions oFunctions = new OutlookFunctions();
    dt = oFunctions.BuildResults(SearchObject.Results);
    this.archiverTaskPane1.DataGridFiller(dt);
}
```

In the ArchiverTaskPane Class (formerly Email_Archiver Form - I REALLY liked the Task Pane idea)

```
private void Find_Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    FindEmails();
}

public void FindEmails()
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();

    //Add columns to DataTable

    //Do stuff to get "searchFolders" and "searchCriteria" from form
    //...

    //Create OutlookFunctions instance
    OutlookFunctions oFunctions = new OutlookFunctions();
    oFunctions.RunAdvancedSearch(searchFolders, searchCriteria);
}

public void DataGridFiller(DataTable results)
{
    EmailList.DataSource = results;
}
```

In the OutlookFunctions Class:

```
public static DataTable RunAdvancedSearch(string[] searchFolders, string[] searchCriteria)
{
    //Get Outlook namespace
    var oApp = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application;
    var oNS = oApp.GetNamespace("mapi");
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Search advSearch = null;

    //Do other stuff to properly set up the scope and filter
    //...

    //Perform search
    SearchComplete = false;
    try
    {
        advSearch = oApp.AdvancedSearch(scope, filter, false, "Archiver Search");
    }
    catch (System.Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("An error has occurred during the search for emails. \n \n"
                + ex.Message);
    }
}

public DataTable BuildResults(Results searchResults)
{
    DataTable resultTable = new DataTable();

    //Do stuff to build DataTable from search results
    //...

    return resultTable;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could refer to the following code about using backgroundwork:

```
BackgroundWorker bw = new BackgroundWorker();
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        bw.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(bw_DoWork);
        bw.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(bw_RunWorkerCompleted);
        if (bw.IsBusy != true)
        {
            bw.RunWorkerAsync();
        }
    }
    private void bw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        //
        // Boring.... Do your long work
        //
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(20000);
    }
    private void bw_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.InvokeRequired)
        {
            //Hide your form here
            this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate { this.Close(); }));
        }
    }
```